# iPhone dealloc and viewDidUnload Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a quick question about the dealloc() and viewDidUnload() methods.  I notice a lot of code examples, people seem to do different things.

Also, I might add that ARC is not an option.

(1)  Should I set all the properties to nil in the dealloc() method including IBOutlets. For example, should I release the instance variable [_myArrary release] and also set self.myArrary = nil.

(2) In viewDidUnload, I think I must set all IBOutlets to nil, and also anything that is created in viewDidLoad.  However, what about myString, lets say it is intialized in another method after viewDidLoad is called.  Should I set that to nil?

If I have some properties declared as such:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *myTableCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myArrary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;

I synthesize them as such:

@synthesize myArrary = _myArrary;
@synthesize myTableCell;
@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize myString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myArrary = [NSArrary alloc] initWithObjects:@"testObject", nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.myArrary = nil;

    self.myTableCell = nil;

    self.myLabel = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{   
    [_myArray release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It shouldn't matter if you set the properties/variables to nil in dealloc because once the object is deallocated you won't be able to access them anyway. With retain properties, doing

   `self.varname = nil;`

   will both release the variable and set it to nil. A lot of people prefer to only release them, I prefer to set retain properties to nil for consistency.
2. In viewDidUnload you should release and set to nil anything that is unneeded and that will be recreated when the view loads again. This is not a strict rule, but good practice to keep as much memory available as possible. If your string will be recreated in viewDidLoad and you won't need to access it until the view is loaded again, then you should probably release it (and I would set it to nil for safety).

   Another note, viewDidUnload does not always get called before dealloc. So you should be releasing every property/variable is dealloc, even if it is also released and set to nil in viewDidUnload. In order to make sure you won't leak when your class is deallocated, your dealloc function for that code should look like this:

   ```
   - (void)dealloc {
       [myTableCell release];
       [myLabel release];
       [_myArray release];
       [myString release];

       [super dealloc];
   }
   ```

   Setting them to nil is also acceptable, but only if you use the synthesized setter, because this also releases the variable.

   ```
   self.myLabel =  nil;
   ```

   is fine, but

   ```
   myLabel = nil;
   ```

   is leaky.

Comment: myTableCell, myLabel, and myString are properties with no instance variable, it is impossible to say [myTableCell release] and I know [self.myTableCell release] is wrong.

Comment: Actually `[myTableCell release]` is correct. Those ivars are created implicitly.

Comment: Depending on the version of the compiler you're using these could all be valid.  @synthesize creates an ivar for you - you've just renamed the `myArray` ivar to `_myArray` but the other properties have identically named ivars.  Furthermore, if you're in `dealloc` you 'could' get away with `[self.myTableCell release]` as long as you're not multithreaded...  But this is overcomplicating it - for now, use the setters and getters as I described earlier, and read the Memory Management Guidelines thoroughly...  Or use ARC - it's available for iOS4 devices too.

Comment: When you create a property and don't explicitly create the instance variable, the instance variable is automatically created for you.

Comment: So even though I never use those implicitly created instance variables, I should release them?

Comment: And in your answer you did [myArray release] wouldn't you release the instance variable [_myArray release]

Comment: By using the property, you are using the instance variables. All a property is, essentially, is an automatically created (synthesized) setter and getter for the ivar. The property itself isn't actually a separate variable.

Comment: And yes, my bad it should be `[_myArray release]`. I have edited this.

Comment: Just to make sure I have this completely clear, I should release all ivar and set each property to nil in dealloc?

Comment: You should set each property to nil OR release its ivar, don't do both or you will overrelease the object.  For non-property ivars definitely release them.  Settings retain properties to nil will automatically release them.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want your `viewDidUnload` to release anything that can be recreated in `viewDidLoad` if your `ViewController` has not been dealloced in the meantime.

In `dealloc`, you need to release anything that the ViewController still owns.  You can't assume that viewDidUnload was called first, so be defensive.

Remember also, there's no harm from sending messages to `nil` - but there's lots of harm from sending release to objects you don't own, or sending it more than once to objects you do own.

Since your properties are synthesized retain, you can avoid having to send `release` yourself, and simply use the setter to set them to nil (`self.property = nil`), assuming of course that you haven't added any extra retains anywhere.

N.B. In your `viewDidLoad` you've explicitly assigned a newly created object to the iVar that your property has synthesized.  Don't do this!  **If another object has set the property between instantiation and presentation, then it will leak**.  Only use the `_ivar` when you know for sure that it is the right thing to do, and you've taken care of every edge case.

TL:DR - Use `self.property = nil` in both `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc` and never assign a new object to an `_ivar` unless you've checked first that it is already `nil` or are prepared to release the previous value.

Comment: self.myArray = [NSArrary alloc] initWithObjects:@"testObject", nil] shows a leak when I analyze it in Xcode.

Comment: `self.myArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"testObject", nil] autorelease]`  or more simply `self.myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"testObject", nil]`

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you elaborate on why you should not set the arrary to the _ivar.  I see a lot of people doing this when they set up arrays and other objects.

Comment: Also, when will these properties be released such as the array.  I am only intializing the array in viewDidLoad.  I just use it value a copy of times throughout the class.  Will that cause problems?

Comment: The reason is - if you've declared the property in your `.h` file then it is essentially public.  If another class instantiates your object, sets the property to something - then the synthesized setter will retain that object for you.  If you then go and clobber it by bypassing the setter in `viewDidLoad` then the previous object is not released (because you bypassed the setter) and thus is leaked.  You may see others doing it in `-init` where it's safer, or if the properties are declared in a Class Extension within the `.m` file and are therefore not 'public'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know it made a difference.  My properties are in the class file not the header so I guess I'm okay there, but that makes sense now.

Comment: Another answer said I should release the implicitly created instance variables in dealloc such as [myString release] is that correct.  I noticed your answer did not say that

Comment: If you use `self.property = nil` then you are already releasing the instance variable.  This keeps it really simple for you: if it is a Synthesized Property, set to nil.  If it's not a property, but a manually created instance variable, then you need to release it yourself.  The current en-vogue style promoted by Apple is to use properties created in a class extension for instance variables.  This allows you to easily set up lazy instantiation, provides forward compatibility for when you move to ARC, and simplifies your job in ensuring there are no leaks / over-releases.